# Пройти по значениям двумерного массива, используя Stream()

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Есть массив массивов строк

```
List<List<String>> list.
```

Хочу каждый внутренний массив запустить в паралельном потоке. И пробежаться по каждому из этих массивов. Передавать значения в функйию checkValue(). Функция возващает булевское значение.
Все значения хочу сложить в переменную result для дальнейшей обработки.

```
List<Boolean> result = list.parallelStream().map(array -> array.stream().map(value -> checkValue(value)))
```

Как это сделать, используя stream()?

Comment: Не путайте массивы  String[][] и списки List<List<String>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы на верном пути, надо только первый `map` заменить на `flatMap` и добавить `collect`

```
List<Boolean> result = list.parallelStream().flatMap(array -> array.stream().map(value -> true)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```